# Label not finding dynamically created element in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, internet-explorer-8

On a webpage I have a javascript function that adds a div with the following hierarchy:

```html
<div style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;">
  <label for="myInput" style="display: inline-block; max-width: 300px;">
    <button disabled style="pointer-events:none;" >Browse to file</button>
    <p style="display:inline">ends up being file name</p>
      <img/>
        <input id="myInput" type="file" style="width:0px;"/>
  </label>
</div>
```

The idea is that clicking anything in the label will trigger the file input, this works great everywhere but IE8.

In IE8 the dynamically create labels don't trigger the file inputs, I've noted that if I change the dynamically created label's 'for' attribute to point to a file input that wasn't created dynamically it works correctly.

It appears the labels can't find the dynamically created file inputs.

Questions: 
 - How to get the labels to see dynamically created file inputs?
 - Is there a way to refresh the DOM to allow the label to see the file input?

Note: If you test this using IE11's Emulation mode it works, but in a real IE8 browser it doesn't

Comment: Does it work in other browsers, because it doesn't seem to work for me in Chrome, and I wouldn't really think it would either ?

Comment: Yes, I just didn't fully mock the code, add the required style to label so it works in chrome, I've edited it.

Comment: Oh, now it works. This is generally not how it's done, most people would just create a button and add some javascript to trigger the input.

Comment: Indeed, however in IE this will cause a security problem and you can't submit the page.

Comment: I did some testing, and it seems to work if you populate the `label` element by using `.innerHTML`.

Comment: @squint, that does the trick, please post an answer and I'll accept, all I have to do is `label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML;` and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but it seems that IE8 enables the expected behavior when you populate the `label` element using `.innerHTML`. There may be other, better hacks that avoid HTML manipulation, but this should suffice as a stop-gap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I've been trying to get this to work for days.., can you share your thought process that made you think of using `.innerHTML` is this a normal debugging method?

Comment: @JoshD: Good question. In my experience, there is no "normal" when it comes to legacy IE. The debugging method is called "grasping at straws". I've come across cases where some view in the DOM wouldn't refresh unless you gave it a kick in the shorts by mutating a style property that wasn't even being used. IE has always had a little weirdness when it came to HTML manipulation and element creation in general. Sometimes it creates (and leaks) invisible temporary nodes when you use `createElement()`, so I thought perhaps adding the `label` to the DOM first would help, but it didn't...

Comment: ... So then I tried `.innerHTML` thinking that it may be broken in such a manner that the behavior was successfully implemented during HTML parsing, but was forgotten during manual element creation, and that seemed to do the trick.